# extracting a json from a document

Tags: couchdb

I am using couchdb for my employee management app. I have created a document in couchdb with the following employees json :

```
{"employees" : [{"id":"123","name":"Henry","address":"HSR"},{"id":"456","name":"Erik","address":"Kormangala"}]}
```

and when I type this on terminal :

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/myapp/9351c38f9a64fd26e40b2ac4cf012efe
```

where 9351c38f9a64fd26e40b2ac4cf012efe is my document id.
i get this :

```
{"_id":"9351c38f9a64fd26e40b2ac4cf012efe","_rev":"7-77b5766b830a3c07c522e9ab17afae09","employees":[{"id":"123","name":"Henry","address":"HSR"},{"id":"456","name":"Erik","address":"Kormangala"}]}
```

what i am interested is only this :

```
[{"id":"123","name":"Henry","address":"HSR"},{"id":"456","name":"Erik","address":"Kormangala"}]
```

How do I do it? Thanks in advance for your solutions and/or advices.

Comment: While I'd recommend just extracting what you need on the client in this case, you could try building a "show" function: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/show.html

Comment: I googled for the use of shows and found that its used to serve JSON in other formats.So, in that case how does it comes to my rescue?i want it as it is i.e. JSON

Comment: The show function can output JSON just as it does any other mime type.

Comment: I second WiredPrairie. "Projections" should be done client-side. It is much more efficient since documents are cached both on the server and the client while shows are computed on the fly.